# What the different between System.Windows.Controls.Page and Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

There are two Page class under [`System.Windows.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page(v=vs.95).aspx) and [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.aspx), when I new a windows phone page, both page works fine. What the different between those two page, and how to choose which to use?

Comment: For starters, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls won't work for WP8 -- only WP8.1 runtime (so you can build an Universal App).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major Difference between them are where are they used and Referenced.

[System.Windows.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page(v=vs.95).aspx) is used for **windows phone 8 Silverlight Application** and

[Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.aspx) is used for **Windows 8 [Windows Store apps]** and **Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Runtime apps] Application** and as well as for **Universal Apps**