# Classes in System Windows controls Namespace VS Classes in Windows UI XAML controls

Tags: c#, class, xaml, user-interface, controls

In developing a small puzzle employing a GridView control in searching for related information I was confronted with two rather different interpretations 
of this control, could someone help explain the different application of these
two definitions.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313184/1532020) probably answers you already, but here's my take on the question.

- "System.Windows namespaces contain types used in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications." ([MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt468159(v=vs.110).aspx)) These you can use for Windows desktop applications.
- Windows namespaces (such as Windows.UI.Xaml) are part of Windows Runtime (WinRT), nowadays called the Universal Windows Platform (UWP). ([More MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx)) You might use these instead if you want to target not only PCs but multiple kinds of devices at once. ([What's a UWP App?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/get-started/whats-a-uwp))

Comment: well explained, concise and to the point for my stage as a dev